# Save and execute an Emacs keyboard macro

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a problem for execute a personal macro in another session in Emacs. I succeeded to create macro and execute then but, after I want to save it for execute them in another time.

For this I write this code in `~/.emacs`

```
(fset 'psTest
     (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro."
       (interactive "p")
       (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ("^X2^X2^X2^X2" 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

but when I call my macro in another file `[ M- x psTest ]`, Emacs doesn't execute my macro but writes `key` in my file

```
^X2^X2^X2^X2
```

all my commands:
In terminal:
`user@PC $ emacs ~/.emacs` 

In emacs:
`C-x (
C-x 2
C-x )
C-x C-k n psTest
M-x insert-kbd-macro [ENTER] psTest [ENTER]
C-x C-c`

In terminal: 
`user@PC $ cat ~/.emacs :
(fset 'psTest
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ("^X2" 0 "%d")) arg)))

user@PC $ emacs ~/test`

In emacs: 
`M- psTest`

Now my macro [M- psTest] write ^X2 in my file instead of execute [^X2] which split the screen.

Where is my error?
Thanks

Comment: I can see that you correctly used `insert-kbd-macro` to generate the code. I don't understand how you managed to end up with an incorrect version of that code in your init file. Certainly if you used emacs commands to copy that code and yank it into your init file, there should have been no problem. Did you use some other technique to copy and paste? You surely didn't type it out manually??

Comment: Yes, I was wondering this also!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the sequence `"^X2"` in your macro definition. It contains two characters `^` and `X` rather than the single character `0x18` in the charset `ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))` which is used by emacs to refer to `C-x` but is displayed the same, though probably in a different color. If you replace the former two-letter-sequence with the latter character and evaluate the definition again, it should work.

You can insert the character with 
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> `#x18` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

PS: To display information about a specific character at point you can use
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `desribe-char` or `what-cursor-position`, which is bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> by default.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **Simon Fromme**.

To insert the `C-x` character, you may omit the `#x` prefix from his answer and type:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

But you may also simply type <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd> in case you don't know the hexadecimal value of the ascii code of this or any other character!

Nevertheless, in your case, I would rather search for the function associated to the `C-x 2` sequence. You'll easily find it is `split-window-below` using either:

- `C-h k C-x 2 RET`
- or `M-x edit-last-kbd-macro RET`

Then you can write some code easier to copy/paste/save like:

```
(fset 'psTest #'split-window-below)
```

or

```
(defun psTest ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-below))
```

This might be a good way to start learning emacs-lisp!